# Allow access to dragged item data on dragenter event handler in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I'm working on a grid component for an Angular 6 application where each cell contains a list of objects that the user can drag and drop to other cells in the grid. Each object has a type and they can only be dropped into cells of certain columns depending on that type. For example, objects of types "PC" can only be dropped into cells on columns 3 and 4, "Users" are only allowed on column 2 and so on. To make it clear to the user, I'd like to highlight in green when an object can be dropped in a cell or red if it's not allowed.

I'm using standard HTML5 drag and drop, so the idea is to set the object type on the `dragstart` event and use it on the `dragenter` handler to do the logic and show the allow/deny state on the drop container· This is part of the code:

```
onDragStart(item: any, e: DragEvent) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    e.dataTransfer.setData("objType", item.objType);

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copyMove";
}


listDragEnter(e: DragEvent) {
    let dragItemType: string;    

    dragItemType = e.dataTransfer.getData("objType");

    if(this.isObjectAllowed(dragItemType)) {
        // THE DRAGGED OBJECT IS ALLOWED IN THIS CELL
    }
    else {
        // NOT ALLOWED
    }
}
```

This works fine on Firefox, but not in Chrome (nor Opera or Safari). I've read that, for security reasons, Chrome only allows to set the event data on the `dragstart` handler and read it on the `drop` one. I understand that there could be malicious iframes that could read  the data, but this measure makes that we can't use HTML5 DnD in cases like these.

Is there any way I could tell Chrome (and the other affected browsers) to bypass this security check and allow reading the event data from `dragenter` events (if they're not being captured on iframes)?.

If not, any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can achieve it by dragstart dragmove and dragend.

Comment: `dragmove`? It's not part of the standard HTML5 DnD events. Is it from a library?

Comment: Ohh sorry it's dragover. But dragenter should work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter

Comment: Yes, the component works perfectly in Firefox, but the problem is that Chrome doesn't allow to read the `dataTransfer` object properties on the `dragenter` handler, only on `dragstart` and `drop`. So my question is if it's possible to make it work on Chrome (and also on Opera and Safari). Thanks.

Comment: You can try `this.innerHTML = event.srcElement.outerHTML; this.innerHTMLX = `${ev.clientX}px`;
            this.innerHTMLY = `${ev.clientY}px`;
            this.innerHTMLS = true;` and in the html `<div  [innerHTML]="innerHTML" [ngStyle]="{'position': 'absolute', 'top': innerHTMLY, 'left': innerHTMLX, 'z-index': '100', 'height': '18px', 'width': '100px'}"></div>`

Comment: First on the dragStart and second on the dragOver

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the question. Drag and drop works, the problem I'm having is that I need to check the dragged data from the `dragenter` handler to allow (or deny) it to be dropped but on Chrome, for security reasons, I can't read this data... I set the data on `dragstart` using `event.dataTransfer.setData()` and I read it on the `dragenter` handler using `getData()` on the same object.

Comment: Yup I used this to replace that It was not working for me aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no workaround here, Chrome doesn't allow accessing the dataTransfer object out of the `dragstart` and `drop` handlers. So, what I did is add a global service to store the dragged object on the `dragstart` event and read it on the `drop` handler.

Something like:

```
itemDragStart(item: Item, e: DragEvent) {
  [...]

  this.globalItemService.setDragItem(item);

  [...]
}

itemDragDrop(e: DragEvent) {
  let item: Item;
  [...]

  item = this.globalItemService.getDragItem();

  [...]
}
```